# In Magento 2 is there a way to disable a third party module if the user is not logged in?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Scenario is Magento 2.3.3.
I have a module that, in the product page, shows a table of colors and sizes available for the product.
I would like to disable this module if the user is not logged in.
I googled it but I cannot find anything.
I'm very new to Magento2 and I need maybe just a hint that points me in the right direction to search for.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Create a check around the table to check if the user is logged. You can't enable / disable the entire module. But you can check the customer and disable / enable based on that.